# ms access vba forms, textboxes, queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, textbox, vba

I am fairly new here.

I am using access 2013 with vba only, no macros.

One table called tblStoreCode with three fields, one being the autonumber, the others are fldStoreCode and fldStoreName.

My form called frmStoreDetails has two textboxes, txtStoreCode and txtStoreName and a cmdSearch button.

What I would like is when a user enters a code into txtStoreCode and clicks the button then the sql statement must look at the value in txtStoreCode and then look in tblStoreCode, find the Code and then display the Store Name in txtStoreName on the form.

I tried so far

```
Private Sub Command9_Click() 
Dim MyString As String 
MyString = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryStore").OpenRecordset.Fields("fldStoreName")
Me.txtName.SetFocus txtName.Text = MyString End Sub
```

Please help.

Comment: way to go ... what you tried so far show the code

Comment: Private Sub Command9_Click()

Dim MyString As String

MyString = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryStore").OpenRecordset.Fields("fldStoreName")
Me.txtName.SetFocus

txtName.Text = MyString

End Sub

Comment: You have a couple of options, but more info is needed. Do you want to allow additions to the data via the form, or is it only for lookup? I assume you currently show a list of all records on your form?

You could place an unbound textbox in your form header, then have vba code for that text box like the following:

    Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
    If Me.txtSearch.Text = "*" Or Me.txtSearch.Text = "" Then
        Me.Filter = ""
        Me.FilterOn = False
    Else
        Me.Filter = "StoreCode= " & Me.txtSearch.Text
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

This how i was doing it-

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click() 
    txtName = nz(Dlookup("fldStoreName","tblStoreCode","aa=" & nz(txtStoreCode,0)),"")
End Sub
```

Or like this if the nz function Complicates you (nz function will help prevent problems when there is null value)

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click() 
    txtName = Dlookup("fldStoreName","tblStoreCode","aa=" & txtStoreCode,0)
End Sub
```

Have fun!